# npm overwrite locally package

Tags: node.js, npm

I have read many questions and articles but I don't have found a solution.

I have an npm package installed into my system, and I'm developing its new version.

I have download my repository make some updates and after I have followed the npm guide so I have done in this way inside my package folder:

```
npm install . -g
npm link
cd ../some-other-folder
npm install ../my-package
```

After these command I tried to launch my npm like:

```
my-package
```

But return me the same thing that old version, updates aren't shown.

How can I fix It?

How can I test my locally updates?

Comment: Are you running "my-package" in cli/terminal?

Comment: sure I'm running from cli/terminal with zsh if is important